# Button in MainActivity, Reset spinner in a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog, spinner

I have two buttons in MainActivity, the first one opens a custom DialogFragment with some spinners and in the other button it resets the spinners of this DialogFragment.

When I click the reset button it calls this method that is in the DialogFragment:

```
 public class FilterDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private View view;
    // ...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filters, container, false);

        // start the spinners and adapters here

        return view;
    }

    public void resetFilters() {
        if (view != null) {
            categorySpinner.setSelection(0);
            productSpinner.setSelection(0);
            priceSpinner.setSelection(0);
        }
    }
    // some more codes here
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FilterDialogFragment filterDialog;
    private Button button_clear;
    private Button button_filter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_clear = findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
        button_filter = findViewById(R.id.button_filter);

        filterDialog = new FilterDialogFragment();

        button_filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show the dialog containing filter options
                filterDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FilterDialogFragment.TAG);
            }
        });

        button_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //reset all filters
                filterDialog.resetFilters();
            }
        });

        //some more codes here
    }
    //some more methods here
}
```

But by clicking the button that opens the DialogFragment, the values of the Spinners remain the same instead of returning the data of position 0 of each spinner.

Would anyone know how to solve this? I've tried everything and I can not.

Comment: please provide all the relevant code. Also, did you create a variable called View, or should your check have view instead (all lowercase)?

Comment: Hi @NikosHidalgo, thanks for support. I update my code.

Comment: I quite don't understand what do you want here. So, the show dialog button works and the reset button doesn't?

Comment: @HauLuu, Sorry for my bad english. That's right, the dialog works, but the reset button does not

Comment: @MurilloComino, have you tried to debug the resetFilters method in FilterDialogFragment? Any change that the view variable is null

Comment: @HauLuu, I performed the debug, but it is not null. I tried the same logic in Kotlin and it works. So in java I ended up doing it another way, follow the answer below. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I ended up finding, was to delete the resetFilters method, and instead I did so:

```
button_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //reset all filters
            filterDialog = new FilterDialogFragment();            }
    });
```